# getting raster brick averages from multiple subdirectories

Tags: r, image-processing, raster

Is there a simple way to get rasters from a set of subdirectories into brick() objects from which I can calculate layers (1 per brick) of their mean values?

I think the second part is easier but funneling everything from the subdirectories is harder for me.

```
dirs <- list.dirs("C:/Data/PROJECTS/Rasters", full.names = T, recursive = T) %>% 
  as.tibble # this list the subdirectories which may contain one or more rasters that i want to get an average value from. 

for(i in 1:length(dirs)){
  setwd(dirs[i])
  f <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = "\\.tif$",recursive = TRUE) 
  BRICK1[i] <- brick(f) # here is the troublesome part for me: I want to add rasters into a brick if the raster is from the same subdirectory defined in my dirs list.
  means[[i]] <- calc(BRICK1, fun = mean, na.rm = T)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward approach would be to handle each directory with `lapply` as a separate list item and apply your functions to it.
This assumes that all rasters you find in each sub directory are compatible for stacking together (extent, resolution, origin ... etc).

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)

dirs <- rep(system.file("external/", package="raster"),10)

dirs[1]
#[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/raster/external/"


brks <- lapply(dirs,function(d) do.call(brick,
                                lapply(list.files(d,'test.grd',full.names = T,recursive = T),
                                       function(r) raster(r))))
```

This might look a bit confusing at first glance, but it's just a nested lapply call:

- First you use `lapply` for your `dirs`, where `d` represents a single directory
- For every `d` you list the rasters contained in the directory (in this case, the pattern is `test.grd`. In your example you would change the pattern to `.tif$`, no need for escaping the period.
- Next, you use `lapply` again for the rasters `list.files` returns for each `d` (since it could be multiple) and load them into an `raster` object
- We use `do.call` to apply `brick` on all raster objects returned by the second `lapply` call, ultimately leaving us with one brick for each list element from the first `lapply` call, which corresponds to your directories `dirs`.

This is how the first two elements of `brks` look like:

```
> brks[1:2]
[[1]]
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 115, 80, 9200, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:28992 +towgs84=565.237,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       :    test 
min values  : 128.434 
max values  : 1805.78 


[[2]]
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 115, 80, 9200, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:28992 +towgs84=565.237,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       :    test 
min values  : 128.434 
max values  : 1805.78
```

If you want to calculate the mean now, you can just use yet another `lapply` call:

```
mns <- lapply(brks,mean)
```

You can see that the bricks in `brks` are identical, but that's just because they have the same input. Also, there's only one layer, because there's only one `test.grd` raster in the package directory.

This example would also work if there would be multiple rasters in the directories. Just mind that the above code assumes that each raster you load has just a **single layer** (otherwise the `raster` function just loads the first one). If you want to handle multilayer rasters, you need to replace `raster` with `stack` in the second `lapply` call.